# Setting state without a removed item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a todo list here using react and firebase. I can successfully remove an item from firebase and add one also. The problem is getting react to re-render after the item has been removed. I was playing around with it and I realize what I'm doing wrong but don't know how to solve my problem.

Here is my componentDidMount method where I set the state to equal the data firebase sends.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.todosRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    const todo = { key: snapshot.key, value: snapshot.val() }
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.concat( todo ) });
  });

  this.todosRef.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
    const removedTodo = { key: snapshot.key, value: snapshot.val() }
    const index = this.state.todos.indexOf(removedTodo);
    this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.splice(index, removedTodo) 
    });
  });
}
```

As you can see whenever I delete a item and call `this.setState({ todos: this.state.todos.splice(index, removedTodo) });` it sets the state to be an empty array (because I'm trying to set the state to the item I just deleted...) which re-renders the page and shows nothing. I would like it to re-render the page and still have the remaining todos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`indexOf` will just look for the object with the exact same object reference, so even if you create a new object with the exact same data as the todo you want to remove it will not work, sadly.

You could instead `filter` out the item with the same `key` as `snapshot.key`.

```
this.todosRef.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const todos = previousState.todos.filter(todo => todo.key !== snapshot.key);

    return { todos };
  });
});
```

Comment: gah! you beat me to it ;)

Comment: This is perfect! `filter()` crossed my mind at one point but wasn't quite sure if I could get it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Splice returns the deleted elements if any. Since in your example you are mutating the array, the new state will be set to the array containing the deleted element.

```
this.state.todos.splice(index, removedTodo);
```

is supposed to be

```
this.state.todos.splice(index, 1);
```

And this should be performed before setting the state.

```
this.todosRef.on('child_removed', snapshot => {
  const removedTodo = {
    key: snapshot.key,
    value: snapshot.val()
  }
  const index = this.state.todos.indexOf(removedTodo);

  let todos = this.state.todos.splice(index, removedTodo);
  todos.splice(index, 1);

  this.setState({
    todos: todos
  });
});
```